# io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection Time out: No further Information:

Tags: io, netty

I am getting the error message: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection Time out: No further Information:

Please, can someone help me to fix it? This error message is on Minecraft and it has something to do with the Netty Project! I have been having this problem for about 3 months now!

Comment: Sounds like a network connection cannot be established... If you have some code, could you post it?

Answer (score 2):

This means the connection could not be established in the configured connect timeout (the default in netty is 10 seconds). So I would check your firewall.